# Geting object from array of array and it's array number

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm using Swift 2.3 and I have the following type array of arrays of my custom object called `Player`

```
`var playing = [[obj-one, obj-two],[obj-three, obj-four]]`
```

How would I use a for-in loop or something else so I can get the array index and the object?

I have the following:

```
for (index, p) in playing { -- Expression type [[Player]] is ambigious
```

I've also tried

```
for in (index, p: Player) in playing { -- same result.
```

and

```
for in (index, p) in playing as! Player { -- doesn't conform to squence type
```

I want to just be able to print out which array the object belongs to and then work with that current object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `enumerated()` to pair up an index and an element, like this:

```
let a = [["hello", "world"], ["quick", "brown", "fox"]]
for outer in a.enumerated() {
    for inner in outer.element.enumerated() {
        print("array[\(outer.offset)][\(inner.offset)] = \(inner.element)")
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
array[0][0] = hello
array[0][1] = world
array[1][0] = quick
array[1][1] = brown
array[1][2] = fox
```

Comment: Thanks, should be `enumerate` for 2.3 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Functional approach:

```
let items = [["0, 0", "0, 1"], ["1, 0", "1, 1", "1, 2"]]
items.enumerated().forEach { (firstDimIndex, firstDimItem) in
    firstDimItem.enumerated().forEach({ (secondDimIndex, secondDimItem) in
        print("item: \(secondDimItem), is At Index: [\(firstDimIndex), \(secondDimIndex)]")
    })
}
```

prints:

> item: 0, 0, is At Index: [0, 0]
>
> item: 0, 1, is At Index: [0, 1]
>
> item: 1, 0, is At Index: [1, 0]
>
> item: 1, 1, is At Index: [1, 1]
>
> item: 1, 2, is At Index: [1, 2]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a for loop, I would do something like this:

```
import Foundation

var playing = [["one", "two"], ["three", "four"]]

if let index = playing.index(where: { $0.contains("two") }) {
  print(index)
} else {
  print("Not found")
}
```

This prints:

> 0

Or to get the entire subarray containing what you want:

```
if let subarray = playing.first(where: { $0.contains("three") }) {
  print(subarray)
} else {
  print("Not found")
}
```

Prints:

> ["three", "four"]